# How do I prevent Safari from creating a new request on a cacheable HTML page?

Tags: http, safari, cache-control

When receiving a http GET request from Safari 6.0, I respond with some html content and the HTTP response header found below.

When pressing Enter a second time in the URL bar in the Safari browser, a new http request is sent to my server. The behaviour I expected was for Safari to get the resource from its cache as is the case for Microsoft Internet Explorer 10 preview.

```
Cache-Control: public,max-age=31536000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 574
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Server: SC
```

Can I prevent Safari from making a new request or is pressing Enter in the URL bar considered a request to refresh the browser in Safari?

Comment: Caches are, almost by definition, implementation-dependant. You should not rely on the cache to prevent a request from occurring, even if it seems to work on some browsers.

Comment: Good then. The tone of your question made me wonder if you somehow relied on it to prevent server-side actions from occurring. Anyways, the HTTP 1.1 specification says that [control over revalidation and reload is fully in the hands of the user agent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) (search for `Cache-Control`), so there seems to be little to do.

Comment: I am not relying on it, I'm doing optimisations. I´m investigating the pros and cons in serving a single page site in one or two requests. The images of the page are embedded in data URLs, so creating an external CSS would make the page go from a single request to two requests. On the other hand, it might improve caching as the second request is always using the cache in Safari.

Comment: From my humble experience, Safari tends to cache resources (scripts, CSS, images) a lot more than content. Besides, data URIs are base64-encoded, and base64-encoded data is roughly 33% bigger as it needs 4 bytes to encode 3. I haven't done any research on the topic and it depends on the files you embed, but I'd be wary that the gains of having a single request are outweighted on the "short term" by the sheer size of the file to get.

Comment: Also, don't forget gzip compression. I suppose you already have it if you're into such fine tuning, but in case you don't, you can get compression ratios of the order of 85% on text resources.

Comment: When gzipped, the 3 bit per byte base 64 bloat makes the actual payload the same as for raw binary PNG. When using CSS and sprites, you get two extra requests (one for the CSS and one for the sprite). Also it is easy to avoid page maintenance headaches with embedded data URLs, as it is fairly easy to let the web server do the merging into a single cachable request when preparing the cached gzip response image. Actually, multiple PNGs gzipped is smaller than using naive html and image links to binaries.

Comment: @zneak - Agreed. In my experience, the compressed base 64 encoded JPEGs and PNGs are about the same as the original binary image. And even smaller (!) when having multiple PNGs on the page.